# Adding a scene above Uiview on CCDirector

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

I want to add a UiView on the CCDirector and a scene on that UIView.
Actually i have some custom Cocoa touch control and that i want to use in my game and above that i need a scene.

Currently i am doing like this.

[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:gridViewController.view];
and after that line i do
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene:[MYScene scene]];

[MYScene scene] returns a CCScene instance.

But what happens that on my custom cocoa touch control is visible but my scene is not visible at all.

Can any one guide me for that how i can accomplish my task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try the opposite approach and have the `UIView` handled as a `CCNode`, then add the node to the scene.

There is even a class that makes this easily possible: [CCUIViewWrapper](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/6889).
If you use it, you can do the following:

```
CCUIViewWrapper* wrapper = [CCUIViewWrapper wrapperForUIView:view];
wrapper.contentSize = view.frame.size;
[self addChild:wrapper z:1 tag:LayerTagUILayer];
```

and you will get both the UIView and the scene added to CCDirector.glView. The `UIView` can be any, you can even define it in IB.

Comment: Hi, I am using spritebuilder to create a game for iphone. and i want to add uiview above ccnode or ccsprite. After looking through spritebuilders API i chould not found any CCUIViewWrapper class. Whould you mind to explain please?